Windows 10 Can't Enter UEFI
I have a custom built PC but I'm unable to enter the UEFI, however Windows 10 is working normally. What should I try next to solve this?

I've tried unplugging all but my single USB microsoft keyboard. Then I spammed a single key each time during boot. I've tried Delete, F8, F10, F11, and F12 since I'm not 100% which key is correct. However I only ever see a black screen and waiting 10+ minutes doesn't seem to help.
Recovery > Advanced Startup > Advanced Options > UEFI Firmware Settings. However this is identical to the previous attempt where I only ever see a black screen and waiting 10+ minutes doesn't seem to help.
I've removed the CMOS battery, but only got a black screen again. Reinserting the CMOS allows me to boot into windows successfully.
I've removed my GPU and tried the motherboard's Display port, but I'm also only getting a black screen.

Additionally, Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > System Settings > Fast Startup is disabled.
Hardware:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
Motherboard: MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super


You should have been able to accessed it using the Advance Startup option. CMOS batteries are required to boot systems.  I assume you don't know what firmware version you are running

according to the manual, the DEL key is the one to use to enter UEFI - also, since your CPU does not have integrated GPU, you can't use the motherboard display connections at all. Try every display output on your GPU (HDMI's and DP's) one at a time

Windows 10 Fast Startup may need to be disabled. https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/how-to-enter-bios-setup-windows-pcs

I had a dual monitor setup, and it looks like once I unplugged the second monitor I was able to see the BIOS/UEFI.
